# How to Return a List<> as Json in Web api c#

Tags: c#, json, json-serialization

I try some way to return JSON but i am not able to do perfectly.
Here is my Code

```
Public string GetData(){
  List<Test> result = new List<Test>();
  // Fill data from Database
  string isonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
  return jsonData;
}
```

Comment: Please provide the errors you're getting

Comment: you are using mvc 5 or dot net core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to serialize it by hand. Just return the list directly:

```
public IEnumerable<Test> GetData(){
  List<Test> result = new List<Test>();
  // Fill data from Database
  return result;
}
```

Or better:

```
public IActionResult GetData(){
  List<Test> result = new List<Test>();
  // Fill data from Database
  return Ok(result);
}
```